# Bigquery: How can I aggregate the data of several columns according to a specific time range?

Tags: sql, syntax, google-bigquery

I am new to big query and I am trying to aggregate transaction data, revenue data, and visitor data across a series of client accounts. I need the output to be grouped by clientname and by 8 month period, so each client account has 12 months of data that are aggregated (each day of the month added together in one month entry). I can only manage to get an out of the first day of each month and not everything in between added together:

```
SELECT
  clientname,
  DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',date), MONTH) as MonthStart,
  SUM (totals.visits) AS visits,
  SUM (totals.transactions) AS transactions,
  SUM (totals.campaigns) AS campaigns,
  sum (totals.totalTransactionRevenue) AS Transactionsrevenue,
FROM `prod.mar.auto` as automotive
GROUP BY 
   clientname,monthstart
ORDER BY 
   clientname,monthstart ASC
Limit 1000
```

The out is only providing the value for the first of the month and not the sum between the months. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: "I need the output to be grouped by clientname and by 8 month period, so each client account has 12 months of data that are aggregated "  . . . This makes no sense to me.  Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data for the last 8 or 12 months, then use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.clientname,
       SUM(a.visits) AS visits,
       SUM(a.transactions) AS transactions,
       SUM(a.campaigns) AS campaigns,
       SUM(a.totalTransactionRevenue) AS Transactionsrevenue,
FROM `prod.mar.auto` as a
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE interval -12 months)
GROUP BY clientname
ORDER BY clientname ASC
Limit 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the question is somewhat unclear, so I'm doing my best with the information I have.

From my understanding of your question, it seems like there is an issue with aggregating across the entire month. It is only returning one day of the month, rather than summing across the month.

If you change

```
DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',date), MONTH) as MonthStart
```

to

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) AS MonthStart
```

This will return the number of the month and therefore you can aggregate across because the numbers across all the date fields will be the same for each month individually.

Here is the final query:

```
SELECT
  clientname,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) AS MonthStart,
  SUM (totals.visits) AS visits,
  SUM (totals.transactions) AS transactions,
  SUM (totals.campaigns) AS campaigns,
  sum (totals.totalTransactionRevenue) AS Transactionsrevenue,
FROM `prod.mar.auto` as automotive
GROUP BY 
   clientname, MonthStart
ORDER BY 
   clientname, MonthStart ASC
Limit 1000
```

Providing Documentation to Function:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

Comment: Hi Madison. Thank you for your response. When I enter DATEPART, it doesn't seem to recognize it ?

Comment: @MarylinMontoya I realized I gave you SQL Server syntax. I just updated with the equivalent in Big Query :)